# saving different type variables in a formated string to a text file in C

Tags: c

I want to save the value of different types of variable in a comma separated csv file. 
right now I have something like

```
printf("[%-2d]|%08x%s[%s][%s][%08x][%08x]", a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
```

what I want is to write in a text file the values like:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Here are the constraints. `a` is an unsigned integer and must be saved just like the `printf` formatted string `%-2d`,

`b,f,` and, `g` are integers but i need to save the hexadecimal value of those variables with the same format used in `printf`, i.e. `%08x`.

I am writing a C program.

Comment: If you are writing a C program, do not tag your question with C++!

Comment: Actually I tagged because C++ programmers may also know the answers.

Comment: No; that's not what tags are for.

Comment: as c++ guy, wouldn't it just be `printf("%-2d,%08x,%s,%s,%s,%08x,%08x", a,b,c,d,e,f,g);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` has its cousin [`fprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) which will happily print whatever you want into a file you've opened/created with `fopen`

```
fprintf(stream, "%-2d, %08x, %s, %s, %s, %08x, %08x\n", a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
```

Answer (score 3):

Does the following work:

```
FILE* filePointer
filePointer = fopen("myFileName.csv", "w");
fprintf(filePointer, "%-2d, %08x, %s, %s, %s, %08x, %08x\n", a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
fclose(filePointer);
```

Comment: thanks. Selecting the user with the lower repo. I was confused about the use of fprintf.